# Replacing values by index with data.table syntax

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

assume we have data.table `d1` with 6 rows:

```
d1 <- data.table(v1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), v2 = c(5,5,5,5,5,5))
```

we add a column to `d1` called test, and fill it with NA

```
d1$test <- NA
```

the external vector `rows` gives the index of rows we want to fill with values contained in `vals`

```
rows <- c(5,6)
vals <- c(6,3)
```

how do you do this in data table syntax? i have not been able to figure this out from the documentation.

it seems like this should work, but it does not:

```
d1[rows, test := vals]
```

the following error is returned:
Warning: 6.000000 (type 'double') at RHS position 1 taken as TRUE when assigning to type 'logical' (column 3 named 'test')

This is my desired outcome:

```
data.table(v1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), v2 = c(5,5,5,5,5,5), test = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,6,3))
```

Comment: Warning is quite useful, try assigning NA_real_ instead of logical

Comment: Or just skip adding test column of NAs, it will be added automatically when assigning a part of new column.

Comment: @sindri_baldur, adding parens is really only necessary if `rows` is a reference to a column in that `data.table` named `rows`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through this:

```r
d1 <- data.table(v1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), v2 = c(5,5,5,5,5,5))
d1$test <- NA
rows <- c(5,6)
vals <- c(6,3)
d1[rows, test := vals]
# Warning in `[.data.table`(d1, rows, `:=`(test, vals)) :
#   6.000000 (type 'double') at RHS position 1 taken as TRUE when assigning to type 'logical' (column 3 named 'test')
class(d1$test)
# [1] "logical"
class(vals)
# [1] "numeric"
```

R can be quite "sloppy" in general, allowing one to coerce values from one class to another. Typically, this is from integer to floating point, sometimes from number to string, sometimes logical to number, etc. R does this freely, at times unexpectedly, and often silently. For instance,

```r
13 > "2"
# [1] FALSE
```

The LHS is of class `numeric`, the RHS `character`. Because of the different classes, R silently converts `13` to `"13"` and *then* does the comparison. In this case, a string-comparison is doing a lexicographic comparison, which is letter-by-letter, meaning that it first compares the `"1"` with the `"2"`, determines that it is unambiguously not true, and stops the comparison (since no other letter will change the results). The fact that the *numeric* comparison of the two is different, nor the fact that the RHS has no more letters to compare (lengths themselves are not compared) do not matter.

So R can be quite sloppy about this; not all languages are this allowing (most are not, in my experience), and this can be risky in unsupervised (automated) situations. It often produces unexpected results. Because of this, many (including devs of `data.table` and `dplyr`, to name two) "encourage" (force) the user to be explicit about class coersion.

As a side note: R has at least 8 different classes of `NA`, and all of them *look* like `NA`:

```r
str(list(NA, NA_integer_, NA_real_, NA_character_, NA_complex_, 
         Sys.Date()[NA], Sys.time()[NA], as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())[NA]))
# List of 8
#  $ : logi NA
#  $ : int NA
#  $ : num NA
#  $ : chr NA
#  $ : cplx NA
#  $ : Date[1:1], format: NA
#  $ : POSIXct[1:1], format: NA
#  $ : POSIXlt[1:1], format: NA
```

There are a few ways to fix that warning.

1. Instantiate the `test` column as a "real" (numeric, floating-point) version of `NA`:

   ```r
   # starting with a fresh `d1` without `test` defined
   d1$test <- NA_real_
   d1[rows, test := vals]  # works, no warning
   ```
2. Instantiate the `test` column programmatically, matching the class of `vals` without using the literal `NA_real_`:

   ```r
   # starting with a fresh `d1` without `test` defined
   d1$test <- vals[1][NA]
   d1[rows, test := vals]  # works, no warning
   ```
3. Convert the existing `test` column *in its entirety* (not subsetted) to the desired class:

   ```r
   d1$test <- NA                   # this one is class logical
   d1[, test := as.numeric(test)]  # converts from NA to NA_real_
   d1[rows, test := vals]          # works, no warning
   ```

Things that work *but are still being sloppy*:

1. `replace` allows us to do this, but it is silently internally coercing from `logical` to `numeric`:

   ```r
   d1$test <- NA  # logical class
   d1[, test := replace(test, .I %in% rows, vals)]
   ```

   This works because the internals of `replace` are simple:

   ```r
   function (x, list, values) 
   {
       x[list] <- values
       x
   }
   ```

   The reassignment to `x[list]` causes R to coerce the entire vector from `logical` to `numeric`, and it returns the whole vector at once. In `data.table`, assigning to the whole column at once allows this, since it is a common operation to change the class of a column.
   As a side note, some might be tempted to use `replace` to fix things here. Using `base::ifelse`, *this works*, but further demonstrates the sloppiness of R here (and more so in `ifelse`, which while convenient, it is broken in a few ways).
2. `base::ifelse` doesn't work here out of the box because we'd need `vals` to be the same length as number of rows in `d1`. Even if that were the case, though, `ifelse` also silently coerces the class of one or the other. Imagine these scenarios:

   ```r
   ifelse(c(TRUE, TRUE), pi, "pi")
   # [1] 3.141593 3.141593
   ifelse(c(TRUE, FALSE), pi, "pi")
   # [1] "3.14159265358979" "pi"
   ```

   The moment one of the conditions is false in this case, the whole result changes from `numeric` to `character`, and there was no message or warning to that effect. It is because of this that `data.table::fifelse` (and `dplyr::if_else`) will fail preemptively:

   ```r
   fifelse(c(TRUE, TRUE), pi, "pi")
   # Error in fifelse(c(TRUE, TRUE), pi, "pi") : 
   #   'yes' is of type double but 'no' is of type character. Please make sure that both arguments have the same type.
   ```

   (There are other issues with `ifelse`, not just this, caveat emptor.)